# Swashbuckle generated Swagger has errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm testing swagger metadata generated by Swashbuckle nuget package against http://editor.swagger.io/ and have the following section in the metadata:

```
     "/User":{
     "get":{
              <snip>
     }
     "post":{
        "tags":[
           "User"
        ],
        "summary":"Create a new user, adds them to a space and sets dashboard view.",
        "operationId":"User_Post",
        "consumes":[
           "application/json",
           "text/json"
        ],
        "produces":[

        ],
        "parameters":[ // This line is marked as an error.
           {
              "name":"user",
              "in":"body",
              "description":"New user's username and assigned space.",
              "required":true,
              "schema":{
                 "$ref":"#/definitions/F1.Birst.CreateUserRequest"
              }
           },
           {
              "name":"Authorization",
              "in":"header",
              "description":"access token",
              "required":true,
              "type":"string"
           }
        ],
        "responses":{
           "204":{
              "description":"No Content"
           }
        },
        "deprecated":false
     }
  },
```

The reported error is:

```
Swagger Error
Not a valid parameter definition
Jump to line 330
Details
 Object
code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
 params: Array [0]
message:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
 path: Array [5]
schemaId:  "http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#"
 inner: Array [2]
level: 900
type:  "Swagger Error"
description:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
lineNumber: 330
```

Code generation still seems to work using NSwag without issues. Is this a problem with Swagger's editor, a problem with Swasbuckle, and why is NSwag able to handle this without issue?

Would other swagger code generators have problems with this?

If it's not a problem with Swagger Editor or Swashbuckle, how would I fix this in my code? The current definition is below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new user, adds them to a space and sets dashboard view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">New user's username and assigned space.</param>
    public void Post([FromBody] CreateUserRequest user)
```

I've tried

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new user, adds them to a space and sets dashboard view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">New user's username and assigned space.</param>
    public void Post([FromBody][ModelBinder] CreateUserRequest user)
```

but that ended up putting the variables into the query string.

**Edit:**

Here is the definition for CreateUserRequest. The validator is throwing errors for the regex (which is valid C# regex). I'm assuming this is due to the validator using JS regex syntax?

Would this be the underlying cause for the "Not a valid parameter definition"? If so, then I suppose it's just a duplicate of the other error. Showing a regex error at the regex, and another error when the class is being referenced as a parameter?

```
  "F1.Birst.CreateUserRequest":{
     "required":[
        "username",
        "space"
     ],
     "type":"object",
     "properties":{
        "username":{
           "pattern":"(?i:^f1(\\.(test|churchstaff|churchuser|internal))?\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$)",
           "type":"string"
        },
        "space":{
           "pattern":"(?i:^f1\\.[\\d\\w]+$)",
           "type":"string"
        }
     }
  },
```

Class definition:

```
public class CreateUserRequest
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"(?i:^f1(\.(test|churchstaff|churchuser|internal))?\.\d+\.\d+$)")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"(?i:^f1\.[\d\w]+$)")]
    public string Space { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the `CreateUserRequest` class and the `F1.Birst.CreateUserRequest` definition? I guess something is wrong with that because when I paste your swagger in the editor it validates perfectly (after adding some mandatory fields and adding an empty object definition).

Comment: @venerik I've added the definitions for you.

If it is all due to regex, how would I solve the validator expecting JS regex, but .NET expecting C# regex?

Comment: Why are you putting your regular expressions in a named group? Without it the Swagger evaluates fine.

Comment: @Venerik what do you mean by "named group"?

I'm using data annotations and actionContext.ModelState.IsValid to handle validation.

Either Swashbuckle or Swagger is using that data annotation in the generation of the swagger class definition.

Can I turn that off for regexes?

Comment: Your regex starts with (?i: and ends with a matching ). That's a named group right? What's the use of that? Can't you just do without that?

Comment: @venerik that's the C# style for case insensitivity. Is there an easier way to do that?  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx

I'll see if there is another way to accomplish it, but that has been an issue I've looked at a couple times. Just couldn't find a solution and didn't realize it was related to those other error errors.

Comment: I'm going to attempt to create a RegularExpressionWithOptions attribute, and pass it in at the Regex constructor level instead of in the pattern.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, good luck. Too bad I could not help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a version of RegularExpressionAttribute that accepts an options parameter, and removing the case insensitive named group from the regex.

**Attribute Definition**

```
/// <summary>
/// Regular expression validation attribute with ability to specify options.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Swagger schema validation fails if you use the (?i:) named group for case insensitive regexes.</remarks>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class RegularExpressionWithOptionsAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    private Regex Regex { get; set; }
    private RegexOptions Options { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that accepts the regular expression pattern
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pattern">The regular expression to use.  It cannot be null.</param>
    /// <param name="options">The options to use for the regular expression.</param>
    public RegularExpressionWithOptionsAttribute(string pattern, RegexOptions options)
        : base(pattern)
    {
        Options = options;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override of <see cref="ValidationAttribute.IsValid(object)"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>This override performs the specific regular expression matching of the given <paramref name="value"/></remarks>
    /// <param name="value">The value to test for validity.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the given value matches the current regular expression pattern</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> is thrown if the current attribute is ill-formed.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"> is thrown if the <see cref="Pattern"/> is not a valid regular expression.</exception>
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        SetupRegex();

        // Convert the value to a string
        var stringValue = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        // Automatically pass if value is null or empty. RequiredAttribute should be used to assert a value is not empty.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
        {
            return true;
        }

        var match = Regex.Match(stringValue);

        // We are looking for an exact match, not just a search hit. This matches what
        // the RegularExpressionValidator control does
        return (match.Success && match.Index == 0 && match.Length == stringValue.Length);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets up the <see cref="Regex"/> property from the <see cref="Pattern"/> property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"> is thrown if the current <see cref="Pattern"/> cannot be parsed</exception>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> is thrown if the current attribute is ill-formed.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"> thrown if <see cref="MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds" /> is negative (except -1),
    /// zero or greater than approximately 24 days </exception>
    private void SetupRegex()
    {
        if (Regex != null)
            return;

        // Ensure base.SetupRegex is called, to check for empty pattern and setup timeout.
        base.IsValid(null);

        Regex = MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds == -1
            ? new Regex(Pattern, Options)
            : Regex = new Regex(Pattern, Options, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds));
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class CreateUserRequest
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpressionWithOptions(@"^f1(\.(test|churchstaff|churchuser|internal))?\.\d+\.\d+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    //[RegularExpressionWithOptions(@"^f1\.[\d\w]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)]
    public string Space { get; set; }
}
```